# how to apply element.bind for particular element only

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

below is my snippet in my directive which calls a controller

```
element.bind('change', function() {
    //alert("inside change function");
    $rootScope.selectedBankName = scope.selectedBankName;
    newvalue = scope.selectedBankName;
    $timeout(function() {
        scope.changeClient();
    }, 500);
});
```

If I use above code It is calling changeclient() function for every element change. but my requirement is I need to call the changeClient function when I change the value in the select box only.please suggest me how to do this.

EDIT:

http://plnkr.co/edit/clTJjlZRlErskt6T0Foc?p=preview

please find the plunker code when I change some value in textbox or dropdown and click any where it is displaying alert box. But my requirement is the alert should be displayed only when I change dropdown value and click anywhere(not for textbox).

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: You need to use the directive on the select box then.

Comment: please find the provided plunker link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an event when the dropdown model is changed, you don't really need to choose to write a directive. Just add a watcher on the select and wait for changes

```
$scope.$watch('age',function(newVal){
    $scope.loadMoreTweets();
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/j3ZR32c4G8PpbLEtrFpZ?p=preview

Edit:

If you really choose to go with the directive code, you can apply the directive on the select itself instead if its parent div

```
<select enter>
```

Comment: I have to include my directive for all the elements that is my requirement and when I load your plunker for the first time itself alert box is displaying before changing the value in the dropdown.

Comment: You could use `<select enter>` instead

Comment: but actually I have to apply the directive as I shown in the plunker only not only for select box I have to apply for each and every element in the div.

Comment: and I should not hard code the value as $scope.age = 19, i should get the value after changing the drop down only.